# Editing .desktop file to run executable as root?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, debian, xfce

I have compiled a c program into an executable that I would now like to integrate into the applications menu in Debian 7.4 XFCE.  In order to run the application under normal circumstances, I am required to type

```
sudo myprogram
```

Now I have created my .desktop file and placed it in /usr/share/applications

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=myprogram
Comment=configuration loader
Exec=sudo loader
Icon=/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/myprogram.png
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE
```

The item is added to my applications menu as expected, and the icon shows up properly.  The problem, however, is that double clicking the menu item to launch the application does nothing.

If I navigate to /usr/bin (where I have placed my executable) and type "sudo myprogram", the program launches as expected.

What can I do to fix this issue and get the program to launch from the menu?  Perhaps /usr/bin is not the correct place to put it, or I have the incorrect Exec command.  I greatly appreciate the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up using (after installing gksu)

```
Exec = gksu myprogram
```

this launches a graphical sudo prompt, which is sufficient for my needs.

Answer (score 3):

The `pkexec` solution from [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118822/how-to-launch-application-as-root-from-unity-launcher#answer-1184444):

```
Exec=pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY APP_COMMAND
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach does not need additional installation of packages.

`Terminal=true` opens a new terminal window which runs
`sudo -i` to ask for the password.
Then, using `sh` to run the program, the Terminal is closed and `myprogram` runs in the background because it has a `&` at the end.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=...
Exec=sudo -i sh -c "myprogram &"
Terminal=true
```

Request: Please report if it works under your OS.
Tested under:

- Xubuntu

Answer (score 0):

This is what the `setuid` bit in the permissions is for. It makes executables run with permissions of the file owner. This only works on actual executables, not on shell scripts!

```
sudo chmod u+s myprogram
sudo chown root myprogram
./myprogram # now runs as root
```

Please be careful when using this as it will always execute that program as root no matter who executes it. You can limit access by setting it to your usergroup and deny all execute.

```
chgrp "${USER}" myprogram # provided you have individual groups set up
chmod a-x myprogram       # deny all execute
```

Answer (score -3):

Try adding this to `.desktop`

`Path=/path/to/myprogram`